# How to host audio files for a web application

Tags: mongodb, audio, meteor, hosting, audio-streaming

I'm planning to make web application which allows users to upload music/audio files and host them etc, i'm wondering what the best method would be to go about this, i have used cloudinary in previous projects for image hosting but nothing for audio.

What do companies like Soundcloud use if not there own service which i am assuming is the case.

What would you recommend? It will be vital when it comes to building a scalable and reliable service so I don't want to go into this project uneducated.

ps. I will be using meteor and mongodb to build the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend getting started with [edgee:slingshot](https://atmospherejs.com/edgee/slingshot) in your app. It's much lighter on your Meteor server since uploads and downloads go straight to the storage system. There you have several choices including S3, Google Cloud Storage, and Rackspace Cloud. You could also use CollectionFS but slingshot seems architecturally better suited to this class of problem.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot for the help, out of those 3 storage services which would you recommend?

Comment: I've only used S3 so far which has been quite good, no complaints. I haven't yet gotten to the point of using multiple AWS cloud sites which I'm looking forward to for global customers. Pricing is going to play a big part in your evaluation I'm sure.

Comment: Just read through to documentation of the package, looks great, excited to get started! Thanks for the information